# Applying the changes from branch A to B, without merging or adding commits

Tags: git, merge, branch

My scenario is that I have one branch in which I've made big improvements to the build process (branch A) and in another I'm working on a unrelated feature (branch B). So now when I'm hacking away at branch B, I want to pull in the stuff I wrote in branch A because I want faster and easier builds. However, I don't want to "pollute" my branch B, just add changes from branchA to unstaged changes.

What I've tried (when standing on branchB):

```
git merge --no-commit branchA
```

Doesn't work because it puts you inside a merge. If it didn't, it would be perfect.

```
git checkout branchA -- .
```

Doesn't work because it applies changes between branchA..branchB and not the changes master..branchA.

Anything else?

Edit: Yes, changes on branch A are committed. In this example there is only one branch with build improvements, but there may be up to N branches with build improvements that I want to apply while working on a feature branch.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

I just had to do something similar and was able to fix it by adding `--squash` to the merge command

```
git merge --no-commit --squash branchA
git reset HEAD # to unstage the changes
```

Comment: This should also have an explanatory note on what its doing as well. It stages the diff of changes from branchA into your current branch

Comment: lets say i just merged code from branchA into master but i forgot something and wanna add few more code/changes into this merge commit without showing up as another merge commit in git history. will this method work?

Comment: @Sushmit I think you can do a `git commit —amend` and it will append the new changes to the last commit, I’m just not entirely sure if it works on merge commits

Comment: I don't think --no-commit is needed here? Should be the default.

Answer (score 17):

`cherry-pick -n` should do what you want, but I'm not sure why you want the build improvements as unstaged changes - that just makes several things harder (e.g. merging other changes to the modified files, or rebasing anything).

> In this example there is only one branch with build improvements, but there may be up to N branches with build improvements that I want to apply while working on a feature branch.

In that case I would create a new branch, C, which you merge from both A and B (and any other branches with build improvements).  Commit changes on the feature branch, B, then merge them to the C branch, which now contains the build improvements and the feature branch changes, so you can test them together. If you need to make more changes do it in the appropriate branch, not C, then merge to C.  So never change anything in the C branch, just use it to integrate changes from other branches.

That means you can use all the features of Git in branch C, instead of juggling uncommitted changes in a dirty tree.

Comment: UseCase for `cherry-pick -n` : I created a working copy of my code by adding lots of stuff to random places. Now I want to clean up my code before I commit to this feature's branch. So I switch to a temp branch, commit all changes. Come back to the feature branch, `cherry-pick` that commit.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: cherry-pick won't accomplish what OP is asking for. While it will apply changes in the desired way (uncomitted) it will only bring in the commit you choose, not the entire branch's changes.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not 100% sure I understood it clearly, but in my case, I've just created diff patch between branches and then applied this patch on the B branch.

Inside branch A:

```
 git diff branchA..branchB > patch.diff
 git apply patch.diff
```

Comment: Excellent answer, this is especially useful since you use the two-dot diff. I was trying to merge branch B to A via a PR, but the diff it showed was three-dot and with inaccurate conflicts.

Comment: I needed exactly that, and so I created the alias `apply-diff-from = "!f() { git diff ..$1 | git apply - ; }; f"`. Maybe that helps someone.

Answer (score 10):

Since git version 2.23, you can use `git restore` to achieve the desired result precisely.

`git restore` provides options to specify *which* files will be "restored" via `--staged` and `--worktree`. It also provides an option to specify *to which* status the files will be restored via `--source`, which is working copy by default and can accept any git object.

Thus the question can be phrased as "restore all files in worktree to status of all files in branchA" and the desired outcome can be achieved with

```
git restore --source branchA --worktree .
```

Instead of all files (`.`), specific files can be given as arguments.

Comment: This is the best and only answer that achieves exactly the result in all cases (even when branchA and branchB are unrelated, which was my case) ! Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to cherry-pick the commits (with `-n` to avoid committing right away).

Comment: -n didn't work. It says no -m option given cherry-pick commit failed.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements.

You can run a merge, then call `git reset HEAD~1`.

---

The following sequence should replay every commit between `master` and `branchA` on top of `branchB`. Commits which were already applied on `branchB` will be skipped.

```
# start from branchA
git checkout branchA
# create a temporary branch wip
git checkout -b wip
# use rebase to replay each commit between master and wip on branchB
git rebase --onto branchB master wip

# if you want to remove all the commit history and only keep the resulting diffs,
# use git reset
git reset branchB

# change the active branch
git checkout branchB
# remove temp branch
git branch -d wip
```

Comment: That adds files to git's staging area which I don't want. Plus, it only seem to work well when all branches are branched from the same commit on the master branch. Otherwise diffs not in the range master..branchA are introduced.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist: remove the `--soft` option if you don't want the changes in the staged area. Could you draw a graph of how your branches are set up ?

Answer (score 0):

For those using VSCode with the Git Graph extension:

> NOTE: All this can be achieved via `git` CLI, as usual.

1. Checkout to the target branch you want to merge the changes into.
2. Open Git Graph.
3. Right-click the source branch you want to grab the changes from.
4. Choose "Merge into current branch...".

   [image: Git Graph - Option to merge into current branch]
5. Select "Squash Commits" and "No Commit" options.

   [image: Git Graph - merge into current branch options]
6. On the Source Control panel, you can then choose to "Unstage All Changes" that are pending. This will put the changes back as unstaged, ready for you to individually pend as new commits.

   [image: VSCode Source Control - unstaging commits]