# How to stash WIP changes at origin?

Tags: git

I work at home and in the office. When changes are not ready to be committed I would like to save them and then retrieve them at home and vice versa. To do this I create a WIP (work in progress) branch from develop. All commits to this branch have as a message "WIP". When some work is ready to be committed I checkout develop and do

```
git merge --no-commit --squash WIP
git reset HEAD
```

and start making proper commits with telling commit messages.

How do you handle work in progress that you want to share across workplaces?

Remark: the idea is taken from [Applying the changes from branch b to a, without merging or adding commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045946/applying-the-changes-from-branch-b-to-a-without-merging-or-adding-commits)

Answer (score 2):

In git, we don't have stash that gets stored on remote. Instead, we use branches to do the job. Branch creation in git is very cheap operation unlike some VCS like TFS.

If you are on develop and have some work in progress, you can just create a new branch from develop, commit your WIP changes in new branch and push the new branch to remote.

Whenever you want to take those WIP changes at another work place, you pull from remote and that new branch will be there in your local. You can checkout and start working again!

Once you are done with your work, you can raise a PR from WIP branch to develop or just merge/rebase develop with WIP branch.

**A note on interactive rebase:**

If you have multiple commits on WIP branch with commit message 'WIP', you can get rid of them and have a single commit [Squash Operation] with a meaningful commit message. You can achieve this with interactive rebase on your new branch.

Assuming you are on WIP branch and there are 5 WIP commits, to do an interactive rebase, 
git rebase -i HEAD~5

Then, in the next window it presents, this will be shown.

```
pick a5
pick a4
pick a3
pick a2
pick a1
```

you can say

```
squash a5
squash a4
squash a3
squash a2
pick a1
```

This will result in commits from a5 to a1 being squashed in one single commit new a1. The rebase window will again ask you to provide a commit message and there you can give your commit message.

Once this exercise is done, you will have just a single commit in your WIP branch and now you can merge this branch with develop.

Comment: Ok, this is what I am already doing but the WIP branch is full of commits with message WIP and when I merge the changes into develop I want to have the freedom of selecting whatever as a proper commit with a proper commit message, just like stash would work locally.

Comment: You can do so with interactive rebase.

Comment: Updated the answer to help you with the interactive rebase.

Comment: In some cases this is what I want. This assumes that I want to commit is a subset of WIP commits. How can I commit an arbitrary part of changes from all WIP commits?

Comment: You can cherry pick whatever commits you want to from WIP branch to develop branch. To do this, checkout develop branch and run `git cherry-pick commitID`. Commit Id is one of the WIP commits you want to take in develop branch.This way you won't have to merge an entire branch  to develop. You can just select which commits should go in.

Comment: the WIP commit are totally meaningless. I don't want to cherry pick WIP commits. I want to have the freedom of deciding which changes (lines of code) I want to commit. Just like with stash. I want all WIP commits to be turned into a single set of unstaged changes.

Comment: You can do so with git reset --soft HEAD~5 on WIP branch where 5 is the number of new commits you want as one change.

Comment: Soft reset will take those commits and bring them in to staging area. If you do a git status, you will see your changes of all 5 commits at once in your staging area waiting for you to be committed.

Comment: so is your suggestion different to what I wrote in the question? `git reset --soft HEAD~5` sounds interesting, will check it out!