# git best way to aggregate sub part of a branch to master without the branch history

Tags: git, version-control, devops

Each time I come across something harder than pull and push with git, I end up fighting doing weird stuff that I could have done probably in one command if I was good at git.

This time I know for sure I am going to reuse the process a lot and I don't want to do it the wrong/long way. So I seek for a git expert to tell me how he would do that. Plus that look like something a lot of people must have wanted to do already.

I have a project on github, and I would like to organize it like that:

### 1: dev branch

The dev branch contains up to date code, and superfluous stuff used for continuous interrogation, benchmark creation folders, doc creation softwares...

### 2: master branch

The master would be a branch that reflects only version changes in the history (ie, each time I reach stable step on **dev**), without the superfluous files used in **dev**.

### 3: why

This organization allows **master** to be an the easy dowloadable point for **every** stable version of **dev**, with the addition of having a clear changelog, while the **dev** branch contains a regular low level technical changes commit history. I think it's really handy.

So I need a way to pull only some folders of the **dev** branch from **master**, but without leaving any trace in the history. Then I need to modify some files (version and readme), commit the result with a version changelog message as the message, and finally push to **master**.

What is the best way to do that according to people versatile in git?

**Edit:**

It would also resolve my problem if I could pull without pulling any unstaged file. This would allow me to configure as wanted master once and just pull with this option for every release.

**Edit:**
Doing: git checkout dev -- LISTOFSTUFFIWANT work. But I dont find any way to ask git to "checkout everything from this branch except those 3 files"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying the changes from branch b to a, without merging or adding commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045946/applying-the-changes-from-branch-b-to-a-without-merging-or-adding-commits)

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449541/how-to-selectively-merge-or-pick-changes-from-another-branch-in-git

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784523/how-do-i-merge-changes-to-a-single-file-rather-than-merging-commits

Comment: When developing your workflow, I'd suggest reading up on established git workflows, if you haven't done this already.  There are several in widespread use, meaning others have found them helpful.  Once you read and understand them, you may want to use one, or still make up your own, with ideas gleaned from widely-used ones.

Comment: From the three links you provided @mkrieger, the best solution I am able to see is to use git checkout <branch from which you want files> <file paths>. If file paths can be a list of folders. The others solutions apply merge on either the whole branch, or on commits, or I can not understand them ;p.

Comment: I checked https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow after what you said @Basya. They seem to take as hypothesis than all the branch have se same set of files. I am going to try to look for more tutorial like that to see if I come across a specific solution for my problem. Maybe the checkout solution is the best. Still waiting for someone to tell me why it is bad.

Comment: The checkout solution would be to write a "release script" that go to master and checkout every intersting path from dev.

Comment: That is a good tutorial; I think I started there.  I am not sure why you say "They seem to take as hypothesis than all the branch have se same set of files.".  Git allows you to add or delete or move files; different commits may have differences in the files they contain.

Comment: I'm also not sure why it bothers you to have all the files in the master branch.  They are part of the project...

Comment: No the linter that is used by the dev team should not be dowloaded by the end user. That just one of many exemples. For the tutorial, as you said in the last comment, they assume everything in dev is relevant for master.

Comment: You're fighting against normal git practices; this is going to be a very annoying and manual process to do. Instead, find a way to only *view* the merge commits in `master` without all the commits in dev. This option might be called ["first parent"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---first-parent) or similar. Also consider instead using `tags` to enumerate the stable releases.